# :nth-letter pseudo-element is not working

Tags: css, firefox

as I build a site for my bakery I would like to make a fancy headline triggering the color for each letter. So I could make use of span but this is exhausting. I wanted to use `:first-letter` or respectively `:first-char` but nothing works. Does anyone of you have an idea how to do it?

Thanks and Saludos!

```
h4 {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "Tangerine", cursive;
  font-weight: normal;
}

h4:nth-letter(2) {
  color: #06c !important;
}

h4:nth-letter(3) {
  color: #c9c !important;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Browser + version number please...

Comment: Firefox, is this the problem?

Comment: Firefox 30.0. This is my standard!

Comment: Looks like it should be fine according to the MDN docs [`:first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter).

Comment: Lol, what do you mean what browser?! That simply does not exist. You are confused with `:first-letter` which does exist.

Comment: @Jonathan Well he did mention `:first-letter` in the title.

Comment: Yes but I don't see that anywhere in the code. He uses `nth-letter` which simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Strangely it does not trigger anything in my css. Though I work with an ordered list and nth-child and this works fine :(.

Comment: `:nth-child` is legitimate. `:nth-letter` is not. Your CSS isn't going to throw an error. It's just not going to render the associated styles. As far as your title goes, I'm not aware of a `:first-char` either.

Comment: `nth-letter` is also supposed to work, see this [link](http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/)

Comment: @DimitriJorge Just because someone wants it to work, doesn't make it work!

Comment: Ho sorry didn't see the small grey box in the intro, my bad

Comment: Okay, I confused the title. It is my fault. Nevertheless I read various articles about nth-letter so I thought it should work. Well, it is kind of frustrating, that this really has to be done with span. Thank you all!

Answer (score 19):

There is no `:nth-letter` pseudo-element (and no `:first-char`) in CSS. The `:first-letter` pseudo-element (which the question mentions in the title and in the prose but does not use in the code) works, but to color other letters, you *must* wrap each of them in an element of its own, normally `span`.

Answer (score 12):

You must be using the js nth-everything-css to enable your browser to support nth-letter feature.

Here's some information on the **nth-everything** [concept](http://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/) (or wish-list), and here (more importantly) is a concrete [implementation](https://github.com/FWeinb/nthEverything) and [example](http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx) of some of those wishes.

Here's [the code from *codepen*](http://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx) (somewhat mooshed) but working.

```
<html>
<style>
    #letters:nth-letter(even){
        color:red;
    }

    #letters:nth-letter(odd){
        color:blue;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://nt4.com/js/jquery"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
  $.fn.nthEverything = function() {
    var styleSuffix = "-nthEvery",
      cssPattern = /\s*(.*?)\s*\{(.*?)\}/g,
      cssComments = /\s*(?!<")\/\*[^\*]+\*\/(?!")\s*/gm,
      partsPattern = /([^:]+)/g,
      nthPattern = /(\w*)-(\w*)(\((even|odd|[\+-n\d]{1,6})\))?/,
      count, parsedStyleMap = {}, genCSS = '',
      runPeriods = function(period, className, a, length, offset) {
        var inBy = 0, sAt = Number(period), n, zB, zE, bF, eF, oldN = -1;
        if (period === 'odd' || period === 'even') {
          sAt = (period === 'odd') ? 1 : 2;
          inBy = 2;
        } else if (/^\d+$/.test(period)) {
          sAt = period - offset, inBy = 0;
        } else {
          zB = (/^(\+|-)?\d+/).exec(period);
          zE = (/(\+|-)?\d+$/).exec(period);
          sAt = (zE) ? Number(zE[0]) : 1;
          inBy = (zB) ? Number(zB[0]) : 1;
          bF = (zB) ? zB.length - 1 : 0;
          eF = (zE) ? zE.length : 0;
          if ((period.substr(bF, period.length - eF - bF).charAt(0)) === '-')
            inBy *= -1;
        }
        // Start index at 0;
        for (n = --sAt; n < length; n += inBy) {
          if (n < 0 || n === oldN) break;
          if (a[n] == null) a[n] = className;
          else a[n] += " " + className;
          oldN = n;
        }
      }, createSpan = function(className, content) {
        return '<span class="' + className + '">' + content + '</span>';
      }, processPeriod = function(classNames, textArray) {
        var newText = '', n, className;
        for (n = 0; n < classNames.length; n++) {
          className = classNames[n];
          if (className == null) newText += textArray[n];
          else newText += createSpan(className, textArray[n]);
        }
        return newText;
      }, prepareTxt = {
        letter: function(text) {
          return text.split('');
        }
      }, pseudoFunc = {
        first: {}, last: {}, nth: {
          letter: function(period) {
            return period;
          }
        }
      }, loopRecursive = function(contents, allText, parsedStyle) {
        var func = parsedStyle.func,
          text, length, classNames, className, cat, period;
        contents.each(function() {
          if (this.nodeType === 1) {
            loopRecursive($(this).contents(), allText, parsedStyle);
          } else if (this.nodeType === 3) {
            text = prepareTxt[func](this.nodeValue);
            length = text.length;
            classNames = new Array(length);
            for (var i = 0; i < parsedStyle.period.length; i++) {
              className = parsedStyle.className[i];
              cat = parsedStyle.cat[i];
              period = parsedStyle.period[i];
              runPeriods(pseudoFunc[cat][func](period, allText, length), className, classNames, length, count);
            }
            $(this).replaceWith(processPeriod(classNames, text));
            count += length;
          }
        });
        return count;
      }, parse = function(css) {
        var matches, nthMatch, nthFound = false,
          i, thisPeriod, selectors, style, selector, parts, nth, pseudo, cat, func, period, normSelector, ident, className;
        css = css.replace(cssComments, '').replace(/\n|\r/g, '');
        while ((matches = cssPattern.exec(css)) !== null) {
          selectors = matches[1].split(',');
          style = matches[2];
          for (i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++) {
            selector = selectors[i];
            parts = selector.match(partsPattern);
            selector = parts.shift();
            nth = parts.shift();
            pseudo = (parts.length !== 0) ? ':' + parts.join(':') : '';
            if ((nthMatch = nthPattern.exec(nth)) !== null) {
              nthFound = true;
              cat = nthMatch[1];
              func = nthMatch[2];
              period = (nthMatch[4] != null) ? nthMatch[4] : cat + func;
              normSelector = selector.replace('#', 'id').replace('.', 'class');
              ident = normSelector + func;
              className = normSelector + cat + func + period + styleSuffix;
              if ((thisPeriod = parsedStyleMap[ident]) != null) {
                thisPeriod.className.push(className);
                thisPeriod.period.push(period);
                thisPeriod.style.push(style);
                thisPeriod.pseudo.push(pseudo);
                thisPeriod.cat.push(cat);
              } else {
                parsedStyleMap[ident] = {
                  element: selector,
                  func: func,
                  className: [className],
                  cat: [cat],
                  period: [period],
                  style: [style],
                  pseudo: [pseudo]
                };
              }
            } else if (nthFound === true) {
              genCSS += selector + "{" + style + "}";
            }
          }
        }
      }, applyStyles = function() {
        var id, parsedStyle, b;
        for (id in parsedStyleMap) {
          parsedStyle = parsedStyleMap[id];
          func = parsedStyle.func;
          $(parsedStyle.element).each(function() {
            var $this = $(this); count = 0;
            loopRecursive($this.contents(), $this.text(), parsedStyle);
          });
          for (b = 0; b < parsedStyle.className.length; b++)
            genCSS += "." + parsedStyle.className[b] + parsedStyle.pseudo[b] + "{" + parsedStyle.style[b] + "}";
        }
        $('<style>' + genCSS + '</style>').appendTo('head');
      };
    $('link[rel=stylesheet],style').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is('link')) $.get(this.href).success(function(css) { parse(css); });
      else parse($(this).text());
    }); applyStyles();
  };
})(jQuery);
$(function() {
    $.fn.nthEverything();
});
</script>
<p id="letters">Hover a red letter. Cool, hu?</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Flavien, that link is just to a site that expressed a **wish** for such elements such as `nth-letter`, that's why someone (not me) down-voted you.  You should add that code-pen link to the article.

Comment: Done… btw it is the same as my (now removed) first comment

Comment: Is it possible to apply this to a textarea?

Comment: I'm puzzled by the "AnB" format of `:nth-letter(2n1)` used in the example. It's not consistent with the "An+B format used by actual CSS3.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine when using ::first-letter.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/n7s75/) fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n7s75/

```
h4 {
  font-size:100px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  margin-top:0;
  padding:0px;
  font-family:'Tangerine', cursive;
  font-weight:normal;   
}   

h4:first-letter {
  color:#06C !important;   
}
```