# how to underline a letter of button caption in vaadin?

Tags: css, vaadin

I'm using keyboard shortcuts in my Vaadin application. So i want to highlight one letter in button caption. The underline might be for first or second or third letter of the caption.

I am able to underline the first letter by using the "first-letter" property of CSS. How to underline second or third letter?

```
NativeButton btn = new NativeButton("Edit");
btn.addStyleName("myunderline");

.mytheme .myunderline.v-nativebutton::first-letter {
     text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Is there any solution?

Thankyou!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I want to highlight one letter in button caption...

You have not specified the vaadin version you are using. But latest vaadin 7 (*> 7.4*) versions support HTML in `Button` caption.

```
NativeButton nb = new NativeButton("<u>E</u>dit");
nb.setCaptionAsHtml(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is posible to indicate it using `&` symbol during shortcut listener creation.

According Vaadin docs:
https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-shortcuts.html

```
// A field with Alt+A bound to it, using shorthand notation
TextField address = new TextField("Address (Alt+A)");
address.addShortcutListener(
        new AbstractField.FocusShortcut(address,  "&Address"));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no simple CSS solution, based on [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705721/nth-letter-why-is-it-not-working) where someone is trying to do the same, and [This Answer](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/5090532) from the Vaadin forums.

Basically, your simplest option is to wrap the letter you want to underline in its own element which applies the underline:

```
<button ...>Te<span class=underline>x</span>t</button>
```

... Or something along those lines. The first link above has an answer which references a number of other JS libraries (lettering.js, nth-everything-css) which might be able to help you out.