# CSS :nth Selectors Header

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, custom-selectors

I need some help with selecting letters/words from headers (h1,h2,..).

This is a CSS Zen Garden, which means I can only use CSS and can't edit HTML. I need to it with css Selectors. I tried using different ::nth selectors but I haven't found a solution yet.

If i could change the HTML i would span the words i need in the header and make it get a new colour but here it's not possible...

I need to select the 10th letter of h3 and change colour to red in section preamble and in explanation section I need to change it too.

I tried using the nth selectors  ::nth-letter, ::last-line,  ::nth-word. ::first-letter works in the third header, but the rest won't.

```css
/*eerste section*/

.preamble h3 {
    font-family: fraktur;
    font-size: 15em;
    color: #4A4A4A;
    margin: 5%;
}

.preamble h3::nth-letter (5)  {
  color:#C54B36;
}

.preamble {
    /* width: 80%; */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    margin: 50px auto;
    /* border: 2px solid #000000; */
    background-image: url('../images/foto1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /*background-size: contain;*/
    background-size: 40%;
    background-position: 93% 82%;
}

.preamble p {
    width: 47%;
    margin: 15px 40px;
}


/*einde eerste section*/


/*tweede section*/

.explanation h3 {
    font-family: baskerville;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 10em;
    max-width: 42%;
    color: #4A4A4A;
    margin-right: 12%;
}

.explanation {
    /* width: 80%; */
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    margin: 50px auto;
    /* border: 2px solid #000000; */
    background-image: url('../images/dame.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: 13% 82%;
    justify-items: end;
}

.explanation p {
    width: 47%;
    margin: 15px 40px;
}


/*vierde section*/

.requirements h3 {
    font-family: fraktur;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 15em;
    color: #4A4A4A;
    margin: 5%;
}

.requirements {
    width: 80%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    margin: 50px auto; 
    background-image: url('../images/fin.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 30%;
    background-position: center bottom;
    justify-items: end;*/
}

.requirements p {
    margin: 0 auto;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 50px;
}

.requirements h3::first-letter {
  color:#C54B36;
}
/*einde vierde section*/
```

```html
<section class="intro" id="zen-intro">
  <header role="banner">
   <h1>CSS Zen Garden</h1>
   <h2>The Beauty of <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> Design</h2>
  </header>

  <div class="summary" id="zen-summary" role="article">
   <p>A demonstration of what can be accomplished through <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>-based design. Select any style sheet from the list to load it into this page.</p>
   <p>Download the example <a href="/examples/index" title="This page's source HTML code, not to be modified.">html file</a> and <a href="/examples/style.css" title="This page's sample CSS, the file you may modify.">css file</a></p>
  </div>

  <div class="preamble" id="zen-preamble" role="article">
   <h3>The Road to Enlightenment</h3>
   <p>Littering a dark and dreary road lay the past relics of browser-specific tags, incompatible <abbr title="Document Object Model">DOM</abbr>s, broken <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> support, and abandoned browsers.</p>
   <p>We must clear the mind of the past. Web enlightenment has been achieved thanks to the tireless efforts of folk like the <abbr title="World Wide Web Consortium">W3C</abbr>, <abbr title="Web Standards Project">WaSP</abbr>, and the major browser creators.</p>
   <p>The CSS Zen Garden invites you to relax and meditate on the important lessons of the masters. Begin to see with clarity. Learn to use the time-honored techniques in new and invigorating fashion. Become one with the web.</p>
  </div>
 </section>

 <div class="main supporting" id="zen-supporting" role="main">
  <div class="explanation" id="zen-explanation" role="article">
   <h3>So What is This About?</h3>
   <p>There is a continuing need to show the power of <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>. The Zen Garden aims to excite, inspire, and encourage participation. To begin, view some of the existing designs in the list. Clicking on any one will load the style sheet into this very page. The <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr> remains the same, the only thing that has changed is the external <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> file. Yes, really.</p>
   <p><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> allows complete and total control over the style of a hypertext document. The only way this can be illustrated in a way that gets people excited is by demonstrating what it can truly be, once the reins are placed in the hands of those able to create beauty from structure. Designers and coders alike have contributed to the beauty of the web; we can always push it further.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="participation" id="zen-participation" role="article">
   <h3>Participation</h3>
   <p>Strong visual design has always been our focus. You are modifying this page, so strong <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> skills are necessary too, but the example files are commented well enough that even <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> novices can use them as starting points. Please see the <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/resources/" title="A listing of CSS-related resources"><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> Resource Guide</a> for advanced tutorials and tips on working with <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>.</p>
   <p>You may modify the style sheet in any way you wish, but not the <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr>. This may seem daunting at first if you&#8217;ve never worked this way before, but follow the listed links to learn more, and use the sample files as a guide.</p>
   <p>Download the sample <a href="/examples/index" title="This page's source HTML code, not to be modified.">HTML</a> and <a href="/examples/style.css" title="This page's sample CSS, the file you may modify.">CSS</a> to work on a copy locally. Once you have completed your masterpiece (and please, don&#8217;t submit half-finished work) upload your <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> file to a web server under your control. <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/submit/" title="Use the contact form to send us your CSS file">Send us a link</a> to an archive of that file and all associated assets, and if we choose to use it we will download it and place it on our server.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="benefits" id="zen-benefits" role="article">
   <h3>Benefits</h3>
   <p>Why participate? For recognition, inspiration, and a resource we can all refer to showing people how amazing <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> really can be. This site serves as equal parts inspiration for those working on the web today, learning tool for those who will be tomorrow, and gallery of future techniques we can all look forward to.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="requirements" id="zen-requirements" role="article">
   <h3>Requirements</h3>
   <p>Where possible, we would like to see mostly <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets, levels 1 and 2">CSS 1 &amp; 2</abbr> usage. <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets, levels 3 and 4">CSS 3 &amp; 4</abbr> should be limited to widely-supported elements only, or strong fallbacks should be provided. The CSS Zen Garden is about functional, practical <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> and not the latest bleeding-edge tricks viewable by 2% of the browsing public. The only real requirement we have is that your <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> validates.</p>
   <p>Luckily, designing this way shows how well various browsers have implemented <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> by now. When sticking to the guidelines you should see fairly consistent results across most modern browsers. Due to the sheer number of user agents on the web these days &#8212; especially when you factor in mobile &#8212; pixel-perfect layouts may not be possible across every platform. That&#8217;s okay, but do test in as many as you can. Your design should work in at least IE9+ and the latest Chrome, Firefox, iOS and Android browsers (run by over 90% of the population).</p>
   <p>We ask that you submit original artwork. Please respect copyright laws. Please keep objectionable material to a minimum, and try to incorporate unique and interesting visual themes to your work. We&#8217;re well past the point of needing another garden-related design.</p>
   <p>This is a learning exercise as well as a demonstration. You retain full copyright on your graphics (with limited exceptions, see <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/zengarden/submit/guidelines/">submission guidelines</a>), but we ask you release your <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> under a Creative Commons license identical to the <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/" title="View the Zen Garden's license information.">one on this site</a> so that others may learn from your work.</p>
   <p role="contentinfo">By <a href="http://www.mezzoblue.com/">Dave Shea</a>. Bandwidth graciously donated by <a href="http://www.mediatemple.net/">mediatemple</a>. Now available: <a href="http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0321303474/mezzoblue-20/">Zen Garden, the book</a>.</p>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to implement your own custom selectors? They aren't just gonna work just because you put them in your CSS.

Comment: It would be something nice that future CSS could do that when you are limited to touch CSS without HTML projects. But for now it is not possible.

Comment: You could use a pseudo element, put an E in it, make it red, hackfix position it and have what you want at the cost of some real ugly solution. Actually... it might even be bit less ugly if you hide the entire title and use multiple elements/pseudo elements to get back a full title.(might not be possible in the markup)

Comment: @BoltClock yes tryed a few. .preamble h3::nth-word(4){
  color:purple;
}

.preamble h3:first-word{
  color:blue;
}

Comment: Uh... I'm not sure you understand what you are doing then. You don't just put a made-up selector in your CSS and expect it to work. It doesn't work just because you imagine that it does.

Comment: It should work, it got the right class and h3 but the nth-selector doesn't work right, might wanna help with an example from you than?

Comment: What @BoltClock is trying to say: you don't seem to understand the very basics of CSS. You can't just go around and make up selectors. It's not that the `nth-letter()` *doesn't work right* - it simply doesn't exist!

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/ It does ctrl F search ::nth-letter() and you will find it xd

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at that:

[image: marking lines on the expected results]

1. Red line splits picture into parts with monocolored font.
2. Blue horizontal lines show that text is not centered - first line simply has an indent.

```css
h3 {
  font-family: Diplomata;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 600px;
  
  text-indent: 1.35em;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 1.35em, black 1.35em);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: white; /* make text readable if clipping is not supported */
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Diplomata" rel="stylesheet">
<h3>The Road to Enlightenment</h3>
```

Browser support: at least actual versions of Chrome, FF, Edge. Doesn't work in IE.

Comment: nice use of `background-clip` and `fill-color`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, don't do this, but I've made a quick example to accompany my comment.

What I did is split the actual title in 3 pseudo elements, of which the 2nd only contains the letter E which I made red.
The original text should somehow collapse, I just chose 0px font-size here as a quick hack that works in most desktop browsers.

This is of course ugly, but it works and is not really bad for accessibility/SEO because pseudo elements are not read out by screen readers(or should not?) and the original title is still there.

```css
.preamble::before {
  color: black;
  content: 'The Road to ';
  font-size: 20px;
}

h3 {
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

h3::before {
  color: red;
  content: 'E';
  font-size: 20px;
}

h3::after {
  color: black;
  content: 'nlightenment';
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="preamble" id="zen-preamble" role="article">
  <h3>The Road to Enlightenment</h3>
  <p>Littering a dark and dreary road lay the past relics of browser-specific tags, incompatible <abbr title="Document Object Model">DOM</abbr>s, broken <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> support, and abandoned browsers.</p>
  <p>We must clear the mind of the past. Web enlightenment has been achieved thanks to the tireless efforts of folk like the <abbr title="World Wide Web Consortium">W3C</abbr>, <abbr title="Web Standards Project">WaSP</abbr>, and the major browser creators.</p>
  <p>The CSS Zen Garden invites you to relax and meditate on the important lessons of the masters. Begin to see with clarity. Learn to use the time-honored techniques in new and invigorating fashion. Become one with the web.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[:nth-letter - why is it not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705721/nth-letter-why-is-it-not-working)

It looks there is no such thing as:

```
:nth-letter(10);
```

**Edit:**

Here is an example of nth-"everything" JavaScript that someone code: https://codepen.io/FWeinb/pen/djuIx

I hope in your project you can add javascript!

Comment: .preamble h3:nth-word(4){
  color:green;
} Doesn't work!

Comment: @Distortion it uses javascript! Take a look at the codepen in the JavaScript column. You can copy it and paste it into your project if you can, otherwise, you won't be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: I can't use javascript in the project sadly, but thanks for the tip. The task is not to touch html (even not adding script line)